# How to disable protected mode for Excel file generated using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

[image]I'd created excel report(.xls) using Apache POI. Whenever I open it, it's showing a message "PROTECTED VIEW: Office has detected a problem with this file. Editing it may harm your computer". How to disable the protected view and Can I handle this within the code itself?

I'm getting the error message only when I apply the style to the cell.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = null;

    HSSFDataFormat dtFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
    HSSFRow row_data = null;
    HSSFCell cell_data = null;

    HSSFCellStyle style = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleSubHeader = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleLeft = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleCentre = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleBRData = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleRight = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleRPrec = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleBold = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleBRight = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleBRPrec = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleBLeftHead = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleBLeft = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleBCentre = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleRRight = null;
    HSSFCellStyle styleSubTitle = null;
    HSSFFont headBold = null;
    HSSFFont titleBold = null;
    HSSFDataFormat dtFmt = null;

    HSSFCellStyle styleCenter = wb.createCellStyle();
    HSSFFont fontCenter = wb.createFont();
    HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
    HSSFFont fontBold = wb.createFont();
    HSSFFont fontsubTitle = wb.createFont();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("sample.xls"));

    try {

        styleSubTitle = wb.createCellStyle();
        sheet = wb.createSheet("Pricing Report");
        row_data = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum());

        style = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_YELLOW.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style.setBorderBottom(HSSFColor.TAN.index);
        style.setBorderLeft(HSSFColor.TAN.index);
        style.setBorderRight(HSSFColor.TAN.index);
        style.setBorderTop(HSSFColor.TAN.index);

        cell_data = row_data.createCell((short) 0);
        cell_data.setCellValue("Header 1");
        cell_data.setCellStyle(styleSubTitle);
        cell_data.setCellStyle(style);

        wb.write(out);

        out.close();

        System.out.println("Excel Generated");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: This is not a problem with `apache poi` but a problem with the location the file was opened from in `Excel`. Read [What is Protected View?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653) and especially [Why is my file opening in Protected View?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653#bm1).

Comment: @ Axel Richter, So you are saying that there is no way to handle it in the code!

Comment: You have read the document behind links I gave you? If you had you would know the answer. If the "code" is able determining the location where the file is stored and this is **not** a "unsafe location" then yes else no.

Comment: You also could follow the `Click for more details` in the message to get more informations why exactly this message is shown. Btw.: The message you are showing in this question seems not to be the exact one you get. To get better answers you also could at least showing the correct message here.

Comment: Yeah, I've updated the question with the proper error message.

Comment: Well then "the file didn't pass file validation. File validation scans file for security problems that can result from changes in the file structure." Then this really can be caused by your code. But we do not see your code.

Comment: I've added the code, the error is coming only when I apply the style. what's wrong with the code? I tried but I didn't find any...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are just another user of ancient versions of `apache poi`. I would suggest you using the last stable version `3.17` instead of that 6 years old `3.9`.

So for all who will find this later: This code is using `apache poi` version `3.10` or lower and will not more work in current versions.

And what do you expect the `style.setBorderBottom(HSSFColor.TAN.index);` will do? The `setBorderBottom` does setting the thickness of the border. This should be `style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);` for example in your version. The setting the border color will be `style.setBottomBorderColor(HSSFColor.TAN.index);`.

This is the problem. The `int` `HSSFColor.TAN.index` is `0x2f` and this is simply not allowed to be a border thickness. That's why `Excel` denies using the file as a safe `Excel` file.

So:

```
...
        style = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIGHT_YELLOW.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style.setBottomBorderColor(HSSFColor.TAN.index);
        style.setLeftBorderColor(HSSFColor.TAN.index);
        style.setRightBorderColor(HSSFColor.TAN.index);
        style.setTopBorderColor(HSSFColor.TAN.index);
        style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
        style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
        style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
        style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THICK);
...
```